# How can I show the model errors in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, view

expected outcome:
I see the errors on top of the screen e.g. presence and length validation errors

actual outcome:
no errors on top of the screen, while I see a rollback in the logs. When I change: `redirect_to :back, alert: @reason.errors.full_messages` at the create action, I do see the error displayed at the top.

situation:

`items_controller`

```
def show 
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @reason = Reason.new
  @reasons = reasons_for_item(@item)
end
```

`show.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(@reason, url: item_reasons_path(@item), html: { class: 'form-inline' }, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <%= f.label "Reason to use" %>
    <%= f.text_field :body, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= f.button 'Submit', class: "btn", id: 'reason-submit-btn' %>
  <% end %>
```

`shared/_error_messages.html.erb`

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`reasons_controller`

```
def create
    @reason = Reason.new(reason_params)
    @reason.user = current_user
    @item = Item.find_by_id(params[:item_id])
    @reason.item_id = @item.id
    @reasons = reasons_for_item(@item)
    if @reason.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to request.referer }
        format.js
      end
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
```

please advise

---

Update 1:
Instead of `redirect_to` I'm going to implement render, as this keeps the model information. Errors still not displaying.

**Update 2:**
Fixed it with adding the form with error_messages to the partial. Now that partial is rendered after the save fails.

Comment: btw, you can use `@reason = @item.reasons.build(reason_params)` instead of separate creating @reason and assigning item_id to it

Answer (score 1):

When you do `redirect_to` it sends the separate request and does not store current state, so the `@reason` is a new entity without errors.
You need to do `render`, instead of `redirect_to`

```
def create
  @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
  @reason = @item.reasons.build(reason_params.merge(user: current_user))
  @reasons = reasons_for_item(@item)
  if @reason.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to request.referer }
      format.js
    end
  else
    render 'items/show'
  end
end
```

Comment: It will render `reasons/show`, not `items/show`. Use `render 'items/show'`

Comment: Yes, you a right. Didn't take into account that it is `reasons_controller`

Comment: `@reason = @item.reasons.build(reason_params.merge(user: current_user))` works. Changing `redirect_to` to `render` also works. But the error does not display.

Comment: Did you try to use `@reason` instead of `f.object`?
And also try to rename `object` in partial to the `reason`. As it could conflict with some method or getter. Not sure, but think it would look better and you will avoid probability of names conflict

Comment: I fixed it, as seen in update 2, I rerender a partial and adding the information to that partial shows me the errors. Thanks for your support